# Does kendo-lint lint kendo-angular code?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to leverage kendo-lint in my angularjs project for static code analysis of kendo usage. Asking this question since I didn't find any direct reference to kendo angular in kendo-lint readme.

https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-lint/blob/master/README.md